# Segmentation Faults - Having Problems Creating New Instance of Array?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, syntax

I am working on a project, I need to store this array dynamically in memory. However I am having problems with seg. faults. I have (attempted?) to create a new instance of the array of the Player class. My program involves iterating through an array of the word horse. I know my algorithm is working (from previous testing) I am just having trouble understanding the pointers and instances/syntax.

all this is a character array declared in header file as

```
char HORSE[5];
```

Here is my code so far I only included what needs fixed for this project:

This is the constructor for the Player class.

```
Player::Player(int n = 0){
    num = n ;
    index=-1;
    Player * HORSE[5];

    HORSE[0] = new Player('H');
    HORSE[1] = new Player('O');
    HORSE[2] = new Player('R');
    HORSE[3] = new Player('S');
    HORSE[4] = new Player('E');
```

}

Here is the method in which I need use the array

```
char Player::add(){
if(index==5)
    return 0;
else {
   word[++index]=this->HORSE[index];
   return word[index];
}
```

}

Comment: `Player * HORSE[5];` is a) not dynamically allocated, b) a local variable in the constructor, and c) totally unrelated to `char HORSE[5];` (which isn't dynamically allocated either). Also, `word[++index]=this->HORSE[index];` is undefined. Don't do several things in one line.

Answer (score -1):

HORSE only exists inside the constructor. Once the constructor finishes it is discarded. You need member variables. Same for index

```
class Player
{
 private:
    Player * horse_ [5];
    int index_;
    ....

}
```

Note I have changed HORSE to horse_. In general all upper case things are constants. And as a good habit you should have naming convention for your member variables.

Now you can go

```
char Player::add(){
if(index_==5)
    return 0;
else {
   word[++index_]=this->horse_[index_];
   return word[index_];
 }
}
```

BTW, use std::vector instead of arrays in c++. They are much nicer

oh yes - and take out that random HORSE declaration you have elsewhere. You put it there cos your code would not compile otherwise, but its totally wrong

As other have pointed out - there are lots of other things wrong here, but this answers your fundamental blocking issue

for example

```
word[++index_]=this->horse_[index_];
```

should be

```
++index_;
word[index_] = horse_[index_];
```

my bet is that word is wrong too , but you dont show how its defnied